# Why does the writer use Present simple with for

Tags: present-tense

I saw  this sentence, I am a bit surprised because of the tense

> We are the number one tour company in the West of Ireland for over 10
>   years!

Why present for a duration? First time I have seen that!

Comment: I suspect that the writer wanted to emphasize "We **are** the number one", because "We *have been*" makes it sound like might be in the past (like "We have been the number one tour company, but we are not number one right now.")  But you are correct to be surprised, and casey's answer is a good one; the whole sentence should have been rewritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tense is definitely awkward. A better sentence could be:

> We are the number one tour company in the West of Ireland **and have been** for over 10 years!